# How to retrieve session value in jsp using struts2?

Tags: jsp, session, struts2

I want to store session value in `String` object in jsp using struts2.

FILE : **header.jsp**

```
<%
name = (String)session.getAttribute("name");    
/* name = (String)request.getSession().getAttribute("name"); */
if(name.equals("cmp")
{  // show something   }
else if(name.equals("emp")
{  // show something   }
else
{  // show something   }
%>
```

When i try to get session value using this syntax i get error : `HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.NullPointerException`

FILE : **loginAction.java**

```
public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware
{
    private Map<String, Object> session;
    private String name;
    //setters and getters
    public String execute()
    {
        session.put("name", name);
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

I set name value based on the user enter name in login page.

Based on the user type i change my header view.

So suggest me how can i get value from the session in jsp and then store into `String` object.

Comment: Do NOT use Scriptlets!!!

Comment: code are in scriplets.

Comment: Do NOT use Scriptlets!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: This is trivially expressed using standard JSP EL or conditionals; why not try a more modern approach first.

Comment: See https://struts.apache.org/docs/ognl.html.

Comment: @RomanC i don't want to print value of object from the session but i want to get session value in String object. So first of all understand my concern and then make it **duplicate**.

Comment: @AndreaLigios if i do not use scriplets then how can i get session value in String object. using `<s:property>` i only print session value but can not get into an object. My need is to store into String object and then check that if value is matched then show something.

Comment: Use the <s:if> tag

Comment: @AndreaLigios <s:if> for condition checking but in first how can i retrieve value of session into String object.

Comment: This is the [perfect example of the **XY PROBLEM**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/214186). **You don't need any `String` in the JSP**. There is no such concept of `String` in a JSP. FORGET STRINGS IN JSPs. You need values, not Strings. Strings in JSPs are like light-years in a calendar. Stop your brain, restart it, then *start thinking **differently***. You need to print ? `<s:property/>`; you need to check ? `<s:if>`; you need to send ? `<s:hidden/>`, `<s:textfield/>`, etc. REMOVE the `<% %>` from your coding dictionary. DO NOT USE SCRIPTLETS.

Comment: @ParthPatel And what are you saying?

Comment: @AndreaLigios thank you so much.   :)

Comment: @ParthPatel you're welcome. Please, stop trying adding me to Skype :D I've two jobs and a family, answering on StackOverflow is enough as free help at the moment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FILE : **header.jsp**

```
<s:if test="#session.role=='cmp'">
    // show something
<s:if>
<s:elseif test="#session.role=='emp'">
    // show something
<s:elseif>
<s:else>
    // show something
<s:else>
```